# How do you create a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which I am following from the jQuery documentation on how to build a plugin.

I'm just trying to create a simple isNot extension:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.isNot = function (selector) {
        return !this.is(selector);
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#someButton").click(function (event) {
        alert($("#someCheckbox").isNot(":checked"));           
    });
});
```

When I run this the javascript file get's loaded properly, and I can step through the code in firebug. I see that jQuery is defined properly, and the click event gets wired up properly, too.

However, I have added a watch in FireBug to track the isNot function, and it is **always** null.  I can't get it to ever become defined.

Is there something I'm not doing properly?

Comment: It works fine here. How are you including jQuery on your page? And how are you including your plugin?

Comment: If you use it as `$` everywhere else, why use a closure to define it as `$` when doing your plugin definition? (Or are these in different files?)

Comment: Your code example works fine for me.

Comment: Even if he is using `$` everywhere *it is a good practice* to use a closure. What if someone else starts to use it, or for some reason he changes the `$`?

Comment: @SLaks when the page loads, and the document ready fires and I hit my breakpoint in Firebug, I have a watch set for $.fn.isNot but it's still null, and it never got created for some reason.  I can't figure out why, it's driving me NUTS.

Comment: @SLaks I'm sorry I take that back, $.fn.isNot is notdefined not null, same for $.isNot

Comment: @BrunoLM jQuery is being included fine, I have a watch on jQuery and $ and it's pulling up just fine in Firebug.  What do you mean by "including my plugin"? I'm just referencing a js file in the page with a typical <script> tag

Comment: It would help us if you could show more context of where your isNot code is in relation to your document.ready code.

Comment: @Alex I did, I have the isNot inside the click event (the code right below the plugin code)

Comment: @Joseph: Could you provide your `script` tags? -- Here is one example that works just fine: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Y5PWv/

Comment: @BrunoLM I just figured out what the problem was I think.  I had two jQuery scripts being referenced. One I was referencing myself, and another one that Telerik was adding dynamically.  I was referencing jQuery 1.4.1, while Telerik was grabbing 1.4.2.  I imagine that referencing two jQuery libraries would cause the plugin not to be wired up properly.  Bruno, if you could answer the question with checking the script tags I'll mark it as accepted, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the way you are including `jQuery` and your plugin is not right.

- Check your `script` tags order.
- Check if `jQuery` is loading properly
- Check if you don't have more than on instance of `jQuery`, which would make your plugin available in the instance that is not accessible anymore.

Here is an [working example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Y5PWv/).

And as you mentioned the problem was really an issue with multiple references to jQuery.

Be careful when using Telerik's external templates, some files contains controls that loads `JS` and/or `CSS` which may conflict with your own.

Answer (score -3):

In your isNot definition the 2nd line needs to be

return !$(this).is(selector);

rather than

return !this.is(selector);

FYI, here is a good article on the jQuery plugin architecture.
http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern

Comment: -1 This is NOT TRUE. *this* is a jQuery object when you are working inside your own jquery functions. See http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/ for more info.

Comment: @Alex: It's even more wrong than that - he's didn't add a `$`; he's just misunderstanding order-of-operations.